# Is it possible to create C# attribute class that would catch function or its overload call?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, overloading, member

I want to log some class member function calls. This class has children with overloads of functions I want to log/count calls.
Is it possible to create an attribute class that would call some static method of my logging on function call?

(That method could call something like             `var declaringType = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod();` if we would not be able to pass into attribute method name in some other way...)

Comment: What you're looking for would be an Aspect Oriented language feature, which is not built into C#. However, code manipulation tools such as PostSharp allow you to achieve results like this. Here's an example of adding logging using PostSharp: http://www.postsharp.net/diagnostics/net-logging

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this purely with an attribute, but you can with something like [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/)

Comment: Is there any way to  inject IL into member or its inheritor via attribute ?

Comment: Not without additional tools, like PostSharp